# Can't update column in sql table

Tags: sql, db2, sql-update, updatable-views

I created a view

```
CREATE VIEW `distance` AS
    SELECT 
        `rv`.`id` AS `id`,
        `rv`.`TIMESTAMP` AS `TIMESTAMP`,
        `rv`.`name` AS `name`,
        `rr`.`distance` AS `distance`,
        `false` AS `new_name`
    FROM
        (`recognition_view` `rv`
        JOIN `raw_recognition` `rr` ON ((`rv`.`rr_id` = `rr`.`id`)))
```

And i need to update `new_name` column, but i get a response Error Column 'new_name' is not updatable. Any way to do it?

Comment: What do you mean "update `new_name`"?  It is a constant, not a column in the table, so you cannot update it.

Comment: Are you sure you're working with Db2? Backticks look suspect.

Answer (score 1):

More than 1 table in the `FROM` clause. This view can't be updatable. Read about [Updatable views](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.dbobj.doc/doc/c0052325.html).
You can create an [instead of trigger](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.dbobj.doc/doc/c0023340.html) to achieve your goal.

Answer (score 0):

The `new_name` is not part of your table(s). It is constructed in your view and always set to `false`. Question yourself this: What would the result of an update on this column be? Where would it be persisted?

If you want to be able to update this value, you should consider adding it to one of your other tables, or create a new table and join it in the existing view.

You could store the `new_name` information in your `recognition_view` or `raw_recognition` table. For simplicity sake, I will explain how to do the latter:

```
CREATE TABLE raw_recognition (
    ...
    new_name NUMBER(1)
)
```

and then in your `CREATE VIEW` change the

```
`false` AS `new_name`
```

to

```
`rr.new_name` AS `new_name`
```

Comment: I update this column in my front-end. And sometimes i need to set `true` to `new_name`.